# How to write User defined error code in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, cassandra

I am writing a Cassandra shell script. I want to add below error codes in the script, so that i can use these error codes in different scenarios.

```
65  Unrecoverable - Script Terminated
66  Recoverable - Manual Intervention needed
67  Warning
```

Comment: Do we talk about exit codes of scripts?

Comment: yes...but user defined error codes

Comment: You can use any code between 0 and 255. The meaning of those codes is up to you (as you are the author of the script)

Comment: How will i define the meaning in the script as i mentioned above script, Could u plz elaborate.

Comment: suppose i executing the command service dse start if[$? eq 0] then echo "successfully installed" else exit 65. Then it should come out of the script and print the Unrecoverable-Script Terminated

Comment: where as for exit 67. it should not come out of the script but to print warning msg

Comment: I am confused, what you want, exit code or print message? Both are possible, but there should be shell to intercept exit code and print custom message.

Comment: yes i want both. error code with customized message

Comment: How can i do that in shell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
service dse start 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
  then echo "successfully installed" 
  else echo "Unrecoverable-Script Terminated" ; exit 65
fi
```

This is just example how to print message and then use custom exit code.

Comment: Thank You!! and for Warning what can i do so that script should not terminate and continue the next commands in the script. Because if will give  exit 66 i:e non zero number it will terminate.

Comment: @Pushpa, you can't have on the same time exit code (which mean exit from script) and continue execution. Of course you can print only error messages and collect exit codes but on the end you can have only one exit code.